# XSLT copy parent element with attributes and change child elements

Tags: xslt

This piece of HTML table

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <p>only one cell without break</p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="3">
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p>text 2</p>
    <p>text 3</p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="3">
    <list>
      <list-item>
        <p>list item 1</p>
      </list-item>
      <list-item>
        <p>list item 2</p>
      </list-item>
      <list-item>
        <p>list item 3</p>
      </list-item>
    </list>
  </td>
</tr>
```

has to be translated into:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    only one cell without break
  </td>
  <td colspan="3">
    text 1<break/>
    text 2<break/>
    text 3
  </td>
  <td colspan="3">
    <list>
      <list-item>
        <p>list item 1</p>
      </list-item>
      <list-item>
        <p>list item 2</p>
      </list-item>
      <list-item>
        <p>list item 3</p>
      </list-item>
    </list>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'm using this piece of XSLT code:

```
  <xsl:template match="td">
    <td>
      <xsl:for-each select="p">
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
          <break/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="* except p"/> 
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

I have to select `<td>` as parent node so I can change all `<p>` tags within one cell with `<break/>` tag for all elements except the last one, where there are more than one `<p>` inside a cell. Where there's only one `<p>` inside a cell, the `<p>` tag has to be removed as well, but `<break/>` doesn't need to be added. All other tags (i.e. list) stay intact. It works, but I am losing "colspan" attribute with this code.

For obvious reasons (manually setting up `<td>`) the attribute colspan isn't copied from parent.

Is it possible somehow to "fix" the code and copy parent `<td>` element with all attributes to output table somehow?

Comment: Is "I also have to use for-each loop as well" some homework requirement? Or what makes you believe you need to use for-each? In the long run writing push style code with apply-templates and template matching gets the job done without any complications.

Comment: I updated the code so it reflects the real issue why for-each (in my opinion) has to be used in this case. If there's another approach, I'd be glad to have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only transformation represented by the samples is

```
  <xsl:template match="tr/td/p">
      <x>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </x>
  </xsl:template>
```

the rest can be handled by the identity transformation (e.g. `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in XSLT 3 or a template spelling that out in XSLT 2 or 1).

After the edit of the question the task is completely different but still in my view to be solved with push style apply-templates and template matching, the two transformations you want are expressed as two templates:

```
  <xsl:template match="tr/td/p">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="tr/td/p[not(position() = last())]">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <break/>
  </xsl:template>
```

the rest will be handled by the identity transformation.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCztv

Comment: Please check the updated example above which reflects the whole issue in this case.

Comment: @Futurion, I have edited the answer to address your new requirements. Still no need in my view to use `for-each` inside of a template and to not rely on the identity transformation to then add templates for the changes you want to perform.

Comment: Ok, this is completely another level for me. It looks so simple, but again, I'd never figure it out. And of course, it works perfectly fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe just one more thing I spotted. I use "Oxygen XML" for editing and it complains about these two templates with "Ambigious rule match" warning. Probably because the first template addresses also some elements addressed by second template. Is this also fixable somehow? Would it be enough to just change the first template to `<xsl:template match="tr/td/p[position() = last()]">`?

Comment: @Futurion, that oXygen message is a warning which can be helpful if you are unsure about template priorities but as the last one of the same priority wins (in existing implementations) the suggestion I made is fine for most use cases. You can of course add more precise conditions to distinguish cases or give explicit `priority` settings on templates to avoid the warning or in XSLT 3 also there is that option on `xsl:mode`: <xsl:mode on-multiple-match="use-last" warn-on-multiple-match="no"/>`.